# Caml Query - OrderBy By Modified not working

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, caml

When i upload a new image using web part. It's not showing the latest image modified. I want to query a image that is latest modified by the time. Example i want the image to displayed by the latest time modified.

Below is my code.

```
 query.Query = @"<Query>
        <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'></Value></Eq>

          <And>
            <Leq>
             <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
              <Value IncludeTimeValue='True' Type='DateTime'> <Now /></Value>
             </Leq> 
          </And>
       </Where>


          <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'/>
          </OrderBy>

        </Query>";
```

Comment: can you share you complete CAML query ? This looks to be a partial one, maybe the issue lies there

Comment: I have updated my full code

Comment: The issue lies on when i want to re-upload an existing image. It should take the latest modified existing image by the modified time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below query:

```
query.Query = @"        
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' />
        </OrderBy>";
query.RowLimit = 1;
```

Couple of things to note, you dont need `<Query>` tag. 
If you just want items based on their modified date, simply use the `OrderBy`. If you only want the latest image, just specify the row limit as 1 which will fetch you only the latest image.

Comment: Can i know why you don't need query tag?

Comment: Well, basically, it's a very common mistake. You probably copied CAML from somewhere like CAML Builder or another forum. For instance, Caml Builder includes Query tag which should not be there when using server-side C# code. You only need Where and OrderBy tags. That's all there is to it. Basically that tag is ignored by SharePoint and causes erroneous  results.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have Value tag inside of OrderBy, your CAML should look like this:

```
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>
```

Comment: Hi vk_muse. I have tried this way but it does not filtered to the latest modified time.

Comment: where do you put this query? do you use it in the code or pass it to webpart property?